# How to build ffmpeg with libfdk_aac in 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

I am trying to build `ffmpeg` on 64-bit Windows with `libfdk_aac`.

I followed [this YouTube guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yhkX0uaQGk) and also [tried these instructions](http://pastebin.com/EdEsMUuS).

None works. The references are old. I get lot of errors. I found these links after searching Google extensively.

Anyone had luck compiling `ffmpeg` with `libfdk_aac`? If yes, could you please share your knowledge.

Comment: If anyone alredy compiled this for win 64 bit, will it be ok to share the binary?

Comment: "I get lot of errors" – maybe you could share those. I don't have Windows and I'm sure compiling FFmpeg there is hard enough. You might also try to post in the [Zeranoe Forums](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/), but please make sure to search there as well and include what you've tried and what specific errors you get.

Comment: It will be tough for me to put all errors here. I tried so many things on the way. I see 99% people using non-windows system. I will try the Zeranoe forum thanks.

Comment: this mentions getting source code with git https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html   and on the same page it links to a  compilation guide which has a section for windows  . haven't tried it though.

Comment: Apparently not easy to compile in Windows. libfdk_aac and libfaac are out of reach unless you compile it yourself.

Answer (score 10):

I used the [Media Autobuild Suite](https://github.com/jb-alvarado/media-autobuild_suite) and it works like a charm<strike>, if you remove the `--enable-libblueray` from the ffmpeg configure line in the `media-suite_compile.sh`</strike>**You probably don't even need to do that anymore**

It automagically downloads the needed compiler and libraries and compiles everything for you. (including the requested libfdk_aac library)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't ***extremely*** care about the audio quality, Native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`aac`) is a nice alternative encoder whose quality is just slightly lower than `libfdk_aac` ([Encode/AAC-FFmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)). Then you can just use [the prebuilt ffmpeg for Windows](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/), which will saves you a lot of time.

Comment: Warning. The native encoder is only "nice" if your audio is single channel. If you have multi channel audio, then the result is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions here on how to compile your own ffmpeg with the codecs you want. It is involved and lots of steps:

http://web.archive.org/save/pcloadletter.co.uk/2011/05/07/compiling-64bit-ffmpeg-for-windows-with-libfaac/

Answer (score -5):

Not a fix for your issue, but if "99% of people use non-windows systems" then VMWare Player (or VirtualBox) and Ubuntu should work.

https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/5_0
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Sorry, but this really does not constitute a useful answer—if the OP wanted to use *nix they'd already have done so.

Comment: I spent almost all my life working with Windows. I moved away from MSFT SQL server to MongoDB last year. But my server side logic is in ASP.NET MVC (C#)

Comment: Never heard of VMWare player. I will use JWPlayer which plays HTML5. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Windows laptop (Win 7) and cross compile FFMPEG to generate the exe that I can use on a windows server?

Comment: @kheya Regarding your last question, no, not possible. Also, VMware Player is just a virtualization solution, nothing comparable with JWPlayer.

Comment: Just brainstorming, would running this on Cygwin be viable?  

For any who don't know:
"Cygwin is a Unix-like environment and command-line interface for Microsoft Windows. Cygwin provides native integration of Windows-based..."

Comment: @kheya if you're not familiar with what vmware is / what a virtual machine is, then you've slept through one of the biggest developments in the last 15 years / post 2000, in computing. But if you're installing on a linux virtual machine hosted by windows 7, then the host is irrelevant, you are installing on linux. It's like not knowing about VNC type applications(pc anywhere was in the 90s).